# Do Hack programmers use runtime assertions?

Tags: assertions, hacklang

In an untyped language, runtime assertions can catch "type errors":

```
<?php
function add_one($x) {
  assert(is_int($x));
  return $x+1;
}
?>
```

With Hack's type annotations, I would want to delete the assertions, but this is unsafe because untyped code may still call typed functions.

```
<?hh // strict
function add_one(int $x): int {
  return $x+1;
}

function evil(): void {
  // UNSAFE
  add_one("yes"); // Runtime error!
}
?>
```

To any professional Hack developers: do you enforce type signatures with assertions? 
(I'd really like to know what Facebook's policy is, but I understand if that's a secret.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Failing to meet a type signature at run time throws an `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`. How you handle this is up to your error handler.

Using `assert` is advised against as it's a configuration-controlled version of `eval`. Instead, Hack introduces the [`invariant`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/function/HH.invariant/) function, which you can use to provide information to the type checker which you know to be true but it can't figure out. Calls to `invariant` are always checked at runtime and will throw an exception if they fail.

So, in your example, I wouldn't have any additional checks as the `add_one("yes");` call will already result in an error at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, having an error handler that converts type annotation failures into something more useful than an `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` and a blank white page is useful. Facebook's throws an exception which we catch at major error boundaries, e.g., so a bug in a single news feed story just causes that one story to fail, and not the entire page.